# PST DONGLE NOT FOUND

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Windows 7 64 bits and I have installed aSitecom Bluetooth adapter 4.0
When click on "V" in Virtual Server (Developer Studio) I get always "Pst dongle not found" I have tried with other two dongles and don't work.
Can you help me please?

many thanks

Comment: Did you install the appropriate driver? Can you see the dongle in the device manager?

Comment: Yes I installed the drivers, the dongle works perfectly because I used to transfer images from my Android phone.

Comment: It is difficult to make a diagnosis based on so little information, but I will try. Next idea: Do you use the correct COM port?

Comment: Where do I select the port inside Bluetooth Developer Studio?

Comment: Ah, wait - do you even HAVE a PTS dongle? The BDS needs the official SIG PTS dongle (at least they claim that, and I never tried anything else). I doubt it will work just with the Sitecom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dongle you are using is actually the official PTS dongle ([bought here](https://bluetoothstore.org/)). Otherwise, I don't think BDS will work with any other dongle.